# Add Readonly to property in runtime - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In ASP.NET, I have a class which has number of properties. All properties are NOT readonly. The class properties are filled using a web-service by other consumers.

When a consumer application consumes the web-service, can I mark some of the properties as readonly in runtime?

Since the class has number of properties and I need the consumer to be able only to change the value of specific properties?

Comment: The class is as the class is. You'd need to use a different class, possibly a wrapper, in that instance I think. An alternative would be to make the properties read-only and only allow them to be set via the constructor. Obviously that's not practical if you need to be able to change the object properties after creation.

Comment: But using reflection, I can remove the readonly in runtime and set the value of the property, can I do the same to set readonly?

Comment: But you're not "removing the readonly". The property is still read-only. You can set private fields using Reflection too but that doesn't mean that the fields are no longer private. It just means that Reflection allows access to members that are explicitly restricted for direct access.  Even if you could prevent setting a read/write property via Reflection, the property itself is still read/write.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications. I will create another class for this purpose.